# Airflow not running on scheduled interval

Tags: airflow

My Airflow webserver is up and running,As other job are running as per scheduled.
I added a new DAG to be executed every 5 minute.
Once added i ran it first time manually and it completed. However after that it is not running again 
every 5 min.

Dag code is below

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_date = datetime.now()
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2019, 6, 11, current_date.hour, current_date.minute),
    "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=1),
}

dag = DAG("Incremental", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *')
```

Suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended. Based on [Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#scheduling-triggers)

In your case, if you have start date of 2019-01-01 00:00:00, 5 minutes interval. You might expect airflow to run at 2019-01-01 00:05:00, but it will run after 2019-01-01 00:10:00 because its waiting for the 5 minutes interval to finish (this is how I imagine it). Hope this helps. :)